# combining tilde expansion with variable substitution in bash

Tags: bash, escaping, command-substitution, tilde-expansion, variable-substitution

Say I'm running bash as root, and I want to chown the home directory of a user `ada`. Say also that `ada` is stored in a variable called `$USER` (because I'm doing this from a script).

When I tried the following,

```
chown -R $USER:$USER ~$USER
```

the shell performed tilde expansion first, so it tried to chown `/home/root/ada`, rather than `/home/ada`.

Is there some way to do it with nested substitions and proper escaping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tilde expansion is tricky and doesn't work with variables like that.

One way is to use `eval`:

```
chown -R $USER:$USER $(eval echo ~"$USER")
```

But make sure your `USER` variable is not coming from untrusted sources.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up here because I had the sort of problem.

I came up with:

```
chown -R $USER:$USER $(getent passwd $USER | awk -F: '{print $6}')
```

But I like anubhava's (slightly scary) `eval` based suggestion better.

Thanks!